# How to use Git to apply a bugfix in a parent branch to the children branches?

Tags: git

I'll preface that I am new to using Git and am still learning how it works. I have a parent branch called "MyProject" where I made some base changes to a model. From there I made multiple branches off from MyProject called "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" etc. where each of the test branches are slightly different versions of MyProject where I turn on or off certain processes for sensitivity tests.

However, I found a bug in the MyProject branch that needed fixing (meaning the children have the same bug). What is the proper way to apply the commit for that bug fix in MyProject to all of the children branches? I only want that particular bug fix to be applied to the children branches and for the other modifications that had been made to the sensitivity test branches (turning on/off processes) to remain the way they were. Is there a simple command or methodology to this, or will I need to go into each child branch individually and do the bug fix manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually (at least) three different ways to accomplish this, with their own pros and cons:

1. Go into each feature branch and do `git rebase MyProject`. This will take each commit in the feature branch and replay it as if it happened on top of the current head of MyProject, instead of at the point where you originally branched off. The end result is the cleanest history, but if the feature branches are complicated you might find yourself doing a lot of conflict resolution during the rebase, and since it rewrites history you need to coordinate it with any collaborators you have so that their work doesn't get stepped on.
2. Go into each feature branch and use `git cherry-pick` to pull in the one specific bug-fix commit. This creates basically four "copies" of the commit, and there's a slight chance of conflicts when you merge the feature branches back in, but usually git does the right thing. This is also useful when your main branch has other changes that you *don't* want on your feature branches right now.
3. Go into each feature branch and do `git merge MyProject` to bring in changes that have happened since the branch was created. This creates a nonlinear history that some people find difficult to navigate, but all in all  it's the most foolproof — there's no history rewriting, and git knows exactly what was merged in, so there are no problems merging back.